# mysql datetime datetime issue on create table

Tags: mysql

Select statement gives proper result but same when used in create table gives error: **ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date** . Any suggestions please?

```
SELECT extraction_id,invoice_date from extracted_fields 
WHERE nullif(str_to_date(invoice_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),FROM_DAYS(0))  >= '2017-04-01'
AND nullif(str_to_date(invoice_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),FROM_DAYS(0))  <= '2018-03-31';


|        210147 | 2017-09-27   |
|        210150 | 2017-10-05   |
|        210208 | 2018-03-22   |
|        210211 | 2018-03-26   |
|        210214 | 2018-03-27   |
|        210453 | 2018-02-09   |
|        210463 | 2017-11-30   |
|        210594 | 2018-03-28   |
|        210663 | 2017-12-05   |
+---------------+--------------+
51968 rows in set, 24328 warnings (0.21 sec)


mysql> CREATE TABLE `tmp_2017-18_list_subu`
    -> AS
    -> SELECT extraction_id,invoice_date from extracted_fields
    -> WHERE nullif(str_to_date(invoice_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),FROM_DAYS(0))  >= '2017-04-01'
    -> AND nullif(str_to_date(invoice_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),FROM_DAYS(0))  <= '2018-03-31';
ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date 


mysql> SELECT @@VERSION;
+-------------------------+
| @@VERSION               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thank you,

Subu

Comment: Do you have any rows where `invoice_date` has a zero value like 0000-00-00?  This sounds like you may be trying to insert new rows while `SQL_MODE` contains `NO_ZERO_DATE` or `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`.

Comment: Yes some rows were having null /characters due to extraction problem. Already fixed it by setting sql_mode flag. Thank you anyways for the response.